# "Map" doesn't have a companion object,

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase db using maps in kotlin.but I'm facing an error called classifier map does not have a companion object and must be intialized here.
I'm writing the line where I'm receiving error.
`var map : Map<String, String>= (Map). snapshot.getValue()`

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator

Comment: ADM can you change this java  code in kotlin please
Map map=(Map). snapshot.getValue()

Comment: It should be something like `var map = snapshot.getValue() as HashMap<String,String>` . read the basics or language before jumping into application it will help you.

Comment: Okay it's working and I'll study more of language now..but can you tell me why we casted it why we are not using it without casting